# React Error Boundaries (предохранители). Странное поведение

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Я хочу написать предохранитель на *React.js*, который бы не позволял какой либо ошибке ломать всё приложение. 
Во время прочтения официальной документации я увидел ссылку на данный пример в 
codepen: https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/wqvxGa?editors=0010

```
class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { error: null, errorInfo: null };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    // Catch errors in any components below and re-render with error message
    this.setState({
      error: error,
      errorInfo: errorInfo
    })
    // You can also log error messages to an error reporting service here
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.errorInfo) {
      // Error path
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Something went wrong.</h2>
          <details style={{ whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap' }}>
            {this.state.error && this.state.error.toString()}
            <br />
            {this.state.errorInfo.componentStack}
          </details>
        </div>
      );
    }
    // Normally, just render children
    return this.props.children;
  }  
}

class BuggyCounter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { counter: 0 };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(({counter}) => ({
      counter: counter + 1
    }));
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.counter === 5) {
      // Simulate a JS error
      throw new Error('I crashed!');
    }
    return <h1 onClick={this.handleClick}>{this.state.counter}</h1>;
  }
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        <b>
          This is an example of error boundaries in React 16.
          <br /><br />
          Click on the numbers to increase the counters.
          <br />
          The counter is programmed to throw when it reaches 5. This simulates a JavaScript error in a component.
        </b>
      </p>
      <hr />
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <p>These two counters are inside the same error boundary. If one crashes, the error boundary will replace both of them.</p>
        <BuggyCounter />
        <BuggyCounter />
      </ErrorBoundary>
      <hr />
      <p>These two counters are each inside of their own error boundary. So if one crashes, the other is not affected.</p>
      <ErrorBoundary><BuggyCounter /></ErrorBoundary>
      <ErrorBoundary><BuggyCounter /></ErrorBoundary>
    </div>
  );
}



ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Этот код **работает** в codepen, я знаю, что там **ошибка в рендере**, она там и должна быть, в тот момент когда "вызывается" throw, то ошибка успешно ловиться и не роняет все приложение (как и задумано).
**Но** когда я копирую этот код, то он работает не так как в песочнице, а именно, в тот момент когда предохранителю нужно словить ошибку, он не славливает, а "кладет" все приложение, 
**Вопрос**: Почему в codepen предохранитель срабатывает как надо, а когда я его закидываю в свои файлы, то все ломается. 
В чем может быть проблема на моем ПК

[Вот фото ошибки у меня в консоли](https://wampi.ru/image/6t6Gtq6) 

А вот фото ошибки на экране:
[image: Фото ошибки на экране]

---

Версия react у меня на ПК: 16.12.0
Версия react-dom такая же.

---

P.S: Код 1 в 1 как в песочнице

Comment: а что у тебя отображается не в консоли, а на экране?

Comment: в общем, предположу, что ты код пишешь с использованием create-react-app и запускаешь его в деве, а там при ошибке выскакивает экран с ошибкой. если так, то в правом углу есть крестик, вот он закроет этот экран и покажет твое приложение

Comment: @WVFFLIFE, а как мне запустить приложение не в дев режиме?

Comment: сбилдить и задеплоить куда-то, например на heroku

Comment: а в чем проблема просто закрыть окно с ошибкой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблемы не было, это было простое сообщение об ошибке из за включенного режима разработки, которое можно было просто закрыть..